# Entity Framework Custom DbSet to overwrite automatic select script / Enumerator

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Currently I got some problems with the automatically generated SQL script from Entity Framework.

I created a database (code-first) with a lot of inheritances and links. Everything worked fine until I added some more tables within my last database migration.

Every time when I now try to access one of my base tables, SQL Server returns an error that a child process is running too long. When I debug through the corresponding code, I can see the `SELECT` SQL script that is generated from Entity Framework automatically. Because of the huge number of foreign keys, child tables etc. the select script contains about 6234 rows.

When I try to run it directly in SQL Server, it returns the same error as Entity Framework does. The error code from SQL Server is 8632.

http://blog.sqltechie.com/2017/03/error-8623-and-8632-in-sql-server-2016.html

So I decided to create a custom implementation of `DbSet` where I can overwrite the automatically generated SQL script. I tried some implementations but nothing worked as I expected.

Is it possible to create a custom `DbSet` with an overwritten enumerator script? 
Alternatively is it possible to prevent Entity Framework from generating all extension table columns as columns of the base table?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is there an option to simplify your database structure?

Comment: I hope that this isn't the only solution for my problem because this means that i have to recreate my whole database which actually contains about >500.000 Datarows.

Comment: What is the LINQ query that generates the large SQL query?  Are you eager loading a large number of related entities in a single query?

Comment: Theres no Linq query. The exception occures also when i try to access the List over the DBSet directly without using Linq. In this special Case the Line where the Exception is thorwn is the following: var m = dbInstance.DatabaseBase.First(x => x.ID == id); But the same Exception is throwing when i only want to access the DatabaseBase-Table directly.

Comment: Even if you could you shouldn't go that path. EF won't have any idea how to generate proper SQL any more. The proper way to modify SQL in command interceptors, but that isn't recommended either. Your only options are: run raw SQL, simplify the class/database structure (start by removing inheritance where possible) or run less complex LINQ statements (split into multiple statements).

Comment: Thats not the answer which I was hoping for. It's hard to understand for my case that you can use inheritance within the entitys but when you need a Flag that every Datarow in the database has to added to you cant handle the flag untyped directly on the Base-Table. I thought that this is one of the great advantages of inheritance but now i'm shocked that I can't use this (for me) fundamental benefit within the entitys because of a SQL-Script that is automatically generated.. I will have a smal look in the command interceptors but it seemed to that i have to completely redesign my Datastructure