# Get Entity Type in Interception for EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, interception

I got some problems with interception in Entity-Framework. In my scenaryo I want to modify the select sql statemant before it is executed by the sql server. I can see the command when i use interception but is there an easy way to get the entitytype for which this script was generated? I cant find any information about the destination Entity within the interception methods.

I created a very simple adaption from the main project.

The Entitys:

```
[Table("Empty", Schema = "Base")]
public class EmptyBase
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ID", Order = 0)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
}

[Table("SoftDele", Schema ="Base")]
public class SoftDeleteBase : EmptyBase
{
    [Column("IsDeleted")]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    [Column("IsActive")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

[Table("ToolTip", Schema = "Base")]
public class ToolTipBase : SoftDeleteBase
{
    [Column("ToolTip")]
    public string ToolTip { get; set; }
}

[Table("Test1", Schema = "Data")]
public class Test1 : ToolTipBase
{
    [Column("Test1Content")]
    public string Test1Content { get; set; }
}

[Table("Test2", Schema = "Data")]
public class Test2 : SoftDeleteBase
{
    [Column("Test2Content")]
    public string Test2Content { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext and Interceptors:

```
    public class DatabaseCTX : DbContext
    {
     public DatabaseCTX() : base(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog = SQL_Interception; Integrated Security = True")
    {
        //Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DatabaseCTX>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Models.EmptyBase> EmptyBases { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Models.SoftDeleteBase> SoftDeleteBases { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Models.Test1> Test1s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Models.Test2> Test2s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Models.ToolTipBase> ToolTipBases { get; set; }
}

public class EFInterception : DbConfiguration
{
    public EFInterception()
    {
        this.AddInterceptor(new EFCommandInterceptor());
        this.AddInterceptor(new EFCommandTreeInterceptor());
    }
}

public class EFCommandTreeInterceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor
{
    public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class EFCommandInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    public void NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext) 
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ScalarExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And at least a small codebehind from my test-app window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{        
    Controls.DatabaseCTX databaseCTX;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        databaseCTX = new Controls.DatabaseCTX();
        //MessageBox.Show(typeof(EF_Interception.Controls.)
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(databaseCTX == null)
            databaseCTX = new Controls.DatabaseCTX();
        databaseCTX.Test1s.Add(new Models.Test1() { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), IsActive = true, Test1Content = "asgsewarasfd asdgasdfgasdf asdfg asdfds", ToolTip = "Nope" });
        databaseCTX.Test2s.Add(new Models.Test2() { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), IsActive = true, Test2Content = "asgsewarasfd asdgasdfgasdf asdfg asdfds"});
        databaseCTX.SaveChanges();
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (databaseCTX == null)
            databaseCTX = new Controls.DatabaseCTX();
        var a = databaseCTX.Test1s.ToList();
        var b = databaseCTX.Test2s.ToList();
        MessageBox.Show(a.Count.ToString() + "_" + b.Count.ToString());
    }

    private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (databaseCTX == null)
            databaseCTX = new Controls.DatabaseCTX();
        var c = databaseCTX.SoftDeleteBases.ToList();
        MessageBox.Show(c.Count.ToString());
    }
```

The problem is that the generated select script in Button_Click_3- Method also contains all fields from all child tables (test1, test2)
In this small example everything works fine but when I use this type of concept in a Big database with 60-70 Tables the generated Select script for the base table is to complex to perform on the sql-server. In normal cases this is no problem because I work with the child entitys (test1, test2) directly but it cames to a problem when I try to change the "IsDeleted", "IsActive" or "ToolTip" property of the entity.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420067/can-i-access-the-entity-in-idbcommandinterceptor-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make changes before saving the dbcontext, you can use the SaveChanges method.

https://exceptionnotfound.net/entity-change-tracking-using-dbcontext-in-entity-framework-6/

Comment: No, I wnat to change the select script from one of my tables to ensure that it didn't fail. I created base tables and inherited all sub tables from these Base-Tables. Everything works fine expect the select script when I try to get the Base-Table entitys. This is because the Entity Framework creates a SQL-Script for the base table with all child table fields.

Comment: @Michael I tried with a sample, this is not the right method

Comment: What do you mean with "this is not the right method"? Do you have a other solution for the problem? I don't want to create delete/activate/... Methods for each entity specialised but i have to do it that way cause the Select-Script for enumerating the base-tables ends with an error 8632 on the SQL server. See my old post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49514024/entity-framework-custom-dbset-to-overwrite-automatic-select-script-enumerator

Comment: @Michael if you want to gain performance you can do this by changing the query, the best way to do this linq for example: expression query by: context.Test1.ToList(); (select * from Test1) linq query by: (from test1 in context.Test1 select new { Content = test1.Test1Content }).ToList(); (select test1.Test1Content from Test1 test1)